# CallScreeningService - Disconnect call after few seconds - Android 10

Tags: android, call, telephony, telephonymanager, android-10.0

Trying to disconnect an incoming call after few seconds of ringing on Android 10. Using `CallScreeningService` for filtering an incoming call.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class MyCallScreeningService :
  CallScreeningService() {


  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
  override fun onScreenCall(details: Call.Details?) {
    if (details?.callDirection == Call.Details.DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
      val phoneNumber = details.handle.schemeSpecificPart
      val blockedList = Paper.book().read(Constants.FIELD_BLOCKED_LIST, ArrayList<String>())
      if (blockedList.contains(phoneNumber)) {
        disconnectCall(details, phoneNumber)
      } 
    }
  }

  private fun disconnectCall(details: Call.Details, phoneNumber: String) {
    Handler().postDelayed({
      respondToCall(details, buildResponse())
    }, 3000L)
  }

  private fun buildResponse(): CallResponse {
    return CallResponse.Builder()
      .setRejectCall(true)
      .setDisallowCall(true)
      .setSkipNotification(true)
      .setSkipCallLog(true)
      .build()
  }
}
```

Problem is, if I set the `handler` time too low, the call gets disconnected without ringing on receiver's side. Although, if I set it higher like 6 secs, then the ringing notification shows, but disconnection doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`CallScreeningService` executes `onScreenCall` method before the phone rings.

You have 5 seconds to decide either to allow phone to ring or to block the call. If you don't return `CallResponse` in 5 seconds time, Telephony API will disregard call to your onScreenCall and let the phone ring.

Using `CallScreeningService` it is not possible to block phone call after few seconds of ringing.